# Launching Messaging application with a body text

Tags: android, android-intent

i have this code to open the messaging. i wanna add body text into it

```
            Intent i6 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse("sms:9986377561"));
            startActivity(i6);
```

add body text

body: test text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra("address", "phoneNumber1;phoneNumber2;...");
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: thanks.. how can i get the lsit of things available via vnd.android.cursor.dir

Comment: thanks a lot :D any resouce u suggest to learn from. i just started android 2 days back