# android.intent.action.SENDTO : Displays activity com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList in Galaxy tab

Tags: android

I have used the intent **android.intent.action.SENDTO** to start the activity for text messaging.

In the emulator and some android phones like htc, the activity that gets displayed is
**activity com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity**. The text message body could also be set .

While in Galaxy tab **com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList** is the activity that gets displayed and the message body could not be set.

The following is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:"));
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", messageBody);

intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

How could I start activity ComposeMessageActivity in Galaxy tab or set the message body if the displayed activity is ConversationList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution. I replaced the intent Intent.ACTION_SENDTO with **Intent.ACTION_VIEW**.

This is the new code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.putExtra("sms_body", messageBody); 
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
startActivity(intent );.
```

This is where I got the solution : 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384174/launching-messaging-application-with-a-body-text)